# Plot a reference near the colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I want to plot a square on the right hand side of the colorbar as a reference with the same color coding (see the image below).

But I couldn't find a way to achieve this goal. Is there any kind and intelligent man that could make this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom legend object and locate it next to the colorbar. Shown in a random plot:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class SquareObject(object):
    pass

# Custom legend object
class SquareObjectHandler(object):
    def legend_artist(self, legend, orig_handle, fontsize, handlebox):
        x0, y0 = handlebox.xdescent, handlebox.ydescent
        width, height = handlebox.width, handlebox.height
        l1 = patches.Rectangle(
        (x0, y0),  # (x,y)
        width / 2,  # width
        height,  # height
        fill=True,
        facecolor="green",
    )
        handlebox.add_artist(l1)
        return [l1]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(14, 6))
im = ax1.imshow(np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10)))

# To locate the colorbar
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.05)
plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax, label="colorbar")

# Add the legend
ax1.legend([SquareObject()],
           ['Reference'],
           handler_map={SquareObject: SquareObjectHandler()},
           loc='right center', 
           bbox_to_anchor=(1.4, 0.8),  #(x, y)
           frameon=False, 
           handletextpad=-0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

You can move the legend with the `bbox_to_anchor` parameter.

Comment: Thank you Francisca, the problem is now solved! You are the greatest!

Answer (score 1):

Just to post it here if someone could have the same question that I did. To get the color from the colorbar, I calculated the corresponding proportion of the given reference in the colorbar.

 `cmap = cm.get_cmap("OrRd")    # get the corresponding colorbar
 reference = 90                            # set the reference
 rgb = cmap( (reference - vmin) / (vmax - vmin) )   # find the color in the colorbar`

finallty, set it to the "facecolor" in the class "SquareObjectHandler".
The location would be the same way. Figure out the coordinates of the colorbar and set the "bbox_to_anchor" in the "legend" accordingly.